# In KDE Konsole edit color scheme - what are color1, color2,...color8?

Tags: kde

New to KDE, trying to figure out how to edit color scheme for Konsole.  I did a bit of looking around.

**Questions**

1. What is Faint Color Column used for?
2. Is intense color used for bold style?
3. What is Color 1...Color 8 used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of digging around I've deduced this (if this is documented somewhere else, pls let me know).

I am going to use LS_COLOR as an example, to describe the mapping.

- Colors are defined with 2 digits.
- 3x - foreground color
- 4x - background color

for example `31` is red foreground `41` is red background.

Normally - the second digit describes the actual color:

0. Black
1. Red
2. Green
3. Orange
4. Blue
5. Purple
6. Cyan
7. Grey

By choosing a color scheme in the `editor color scheme` we are mapping the numbers to a different set of colors.

1. color 2
2. color 3
3. color 4
4. color 5
5. color 6
6. color 7
7. color 8

I am assuming that 00 - is foreground & 10 - is the background.

So by choosing `Black on Light Yellow` we have mapped:

- `31` to first-column of `Color 2`
- `01;31` to second-column of `Color 2` - (This will also bold the font)
- `02;31` to third-column of `Color 2`

[image]

For further reading on LS_COLOR:

- [describes](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/2ypqui/converting_rgb_hex_color_codes_into_the_ls_colors/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) the schema for color definition
- [describes](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) LS_COLORS in general

Comment: Actually, LS_COLOR has nothing to do with Konsole color schemes, this variable is used to set colors for `ls` command output. *But* it uses the same escape code sequences that are used in terminal in order to obtain colored output. I added my own answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions starting from the last. There are 8 basic colors numbered from 0 to 7. They are named as Color 1 — Color 8 in the first column of colors in Konsole's Color Scheme Editor. There are another 8 colors which can be obtained from the basic colors using "Intense" attribute. And if you've got "Draw intense colors in bold font" enabled on "Appearance" tab of Konsole Profile's Settings then these intense colors will be rendered in bold. They comprise the second column of colors of the color scheme. Yet another 8 colors can be obtained from the basic colors using "Faint" attribute. They'll comprise the last column of colors.

Actually escape sequence used for color formatting in terminal consists of *three* codes:
`\e[ATTRIBUTE;FG_COLOR;BG_COLORm`
ATTRIBUTE can be: 00 — which means normal text (this code also clears all other currently applied attributes), 01 — which means increased intensity, 02 — which means decreased intensity, and there are more. Codes 30 — 37 set 8 colors for the foreground text and codes 40 — 47 set colors for the background.
To explain on example I'll omit backround codes for the sake of simplicity. If you run the command below in your terminal you'll get all three colors in the row named "Color 3" in Konsole's Color Scheme Editor (corresponding foreground code is 32):

```
echo -e '\e[00;32mNormal \e[01;32mIntense\e[00m \e[02;32mFaint\e[00m'
```

Replace "32" in this command with 35 and you'll receive the row of colors named as "Color 6".

Konsole is capable to produce 256 colors, but their coding is beyond the scope of your question. There's comprehensive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4842424#33206814) describing this in detail.